# JavaFX 8 - Alert not open

Tags: java

I'm developing a little Server-Client-System for Chess. Users can ask other Users for a game and there's my problem. The Client sends a message to the server, the server sends the message directly to the other Client and the other Client gets the message. After getting the message, the Client should open an Alert to choose if he wants to play with the other Client, but it simply does not open. Here's my code

```
} else if (readed.equals("+anfrage")){
    String n=clientSocket.readLine();
    Alert in=new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);     //here the program stucks
    in.setHeaderText("Spielanfrage von: "+n);
    in.getButtonTypes().clear();
    in.getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
    in.setResizable(false);
    Optional<ButtonType> opt=in.showAndWait();
    if (opt.get()==ButtonType.YES) {

    } else{

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, " Your Message" + selection + " ?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO, ButtonType.CANCEL);
alert.showAndWait();

if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.YES) {
    //do stuff
}else{
   //do other stuffs
}
```